# What is the meaning of these C Macros (protos, #x?, __unused)?

Tags: c, macros

```
#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
#define __P(protos) protos      /* full-blown ANSI C */
#define __CONCAT(x,y)   x ## y
#define __STRING(x) #x


 #define    __unused    __attribute__((__unused__))
 #define    __dead2     __attribute__((__noreturn__))
 #define    __pure2     __attribute__((__const__))
```

1. What's `protos`? Where is it defined?
2. What's `#x`?
3. Why need `__unused` when `__unused__` already existed?
4. Where are `__const__`, `__noreturn__`, `__unused__` defined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `protos` is the macro parameter. It's defined in `__P(protos)` and its scope is until the end of the line. In this case, the macro invocation `int func(__P(int foo))` would be replaced by `int func(int foo)`, which is an "ANSI style" function prototype, as opposed to pre-standard C which did not necessarily declare function parameters. On such a pre-standard compiler, the macro would be defined with no expansion, so the compiler would see only `int func()`.
2. `#x` is the stringize operator. It turns the content of its argument `x` into a string by adding quotes. If the argument passed to `x` contains macros, they are not expanded before the string conversion is done.
3. These macros are used to define different things for different platforms. `__unused` might expand to different things on GCC or MSVC.
4. They are hooks to the inside of the compiler. The header file is providing an interface between the compiler internals and the standard language. The compiler could work directly with `__unused` as an extension keyword, but its authors preferred to define a uniform interface around `__attribute__`.

Answer (score 4):

1. `protos` is a parameter of `__P` which is just passed.
2. `#x` means to make a string out of `x`. `__STRING(abc)` is replaced by `"abc"`
3. Probably maintenance, cross-platform or uniformity reasons. Hard to know without context.
4. Compiler extension. See your compiler's documentation.